# Why do cable and TV have watermarks on their programming?

Tags: film-industry

When I first got Cable TV I noted that most programs had an intrusive logo on the top or bottom corners that distract from the movie watching. In time I canceled my subscription as I didn't see why I should pay for programming when I can see it logo free on TV.

Then..

About 10 or so years ago, well at least in my country, TV stations started doing the same thing by adding these intrusive logos to the programming. To me its a form of vandalism and can spoil a movie. Especially when there is a dark scene and you see their logo blaring on the screen.

For paid TV I cannot understand, for TV I can sort of see a reason as we started to get DVD recorders and the resolution of the programming the TV stations were sending are at a fairly high quality, so piracy was a possibility.

But for a paid service like Foxtel (Australian Cable Provider) to charge $100 a month with this on the screen I think is loosing them business.

So the question I have, is there some rule/regulation from the content providers that say when broadcasting on TV they have to add a station logo?

Comment: Are you talking about the usual small logo of the TV channel that is in one of the corners? Interresting, because I don't know it any different, it's been standard here in Germany for all of my lifetime (well, at least the last 20 years, but I guess since ever (the 50s)) and I thought this to have been the case everywhere and anytime. I guess it's rather in the interrest of the channels than the content providers (movies), since it's effectively a continous advertisement and reminder of the channel.

Comment: @ChristianRau Then maybe the new generation doesn't even know and its only older folks like me that notice. But I have switched from TV to youtube and AppleTV to avoid the "little" logo

Comment: It was also a way of quickly identifying which channel you were on back when you had to tune them manually.

Comment: @hammer So the big knob you turned and made click click noises as you turned the dial that finally landed on a number wasn't enough of a clue? Lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there some rule/regulation from the content providers that say when broadcasting on TV they have to add a station logo?

Only because they've bought / recorded / invested their own money for the broadcasting program. It's a copyright. What will they do, if you record their program and broadcast on your own, or just sell it somewhere? (*similar to plagiarizing*). Other than their logo, the stations also use some kind of watermark in their channels that can be easily noted if you closely look into it. It is much visible if you record the event. [This wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_on-screen_graphic) is good.

Comment: It wouldn't bother me so much if they actually stuck it in the corner of the screen - it's usually a good 2-3 inches from both edges (depending on the size of your TV).